# Java what .read() function returns ? And Java IOException

Tags: java, function, exception, file-io

I have this line of code.And numbers.txt has a string of these numbers : 123456789 .Running it prints : 235689 . Why?  What does .read() do ? And when 'while(fin.read() > -1 )' is TRUE? Also about the Exception why i get IOException Error when not using it since the program is correct?

```
import java.io.*;

public class Read {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {



        FileReader fin = new FileReader("numbers.txt");

        while(fin.read() > -1 ){

         System.out.print((char) fin.read());
         System.out.print((char) fin.read());

        }
        fin.close(); 


    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are discarding every third character.  I suggest storing the character you read and printing that.

```
for(int ch; (ch = fin.read()) > -1; )
     System.out.print((char) ch);
```

I suggest you use a BufferedReader instead like this

```
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("numbers.txt"))) {
    for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; )
        System.out.println(line);
} // closes the br
```

Comment: That is not a problem its for studying only.I am just trying to understand how while(fin.read() > -1 ) exactly works. How it discarding every third character ?

Comment: @KonstantinosKorovesis you are reading it, checking it is > -1 and throwing it away. The next fin.read() will be the next byte/character.

Comment: It's disarding every third character because you are not storing the result of `(fin.read() > 1)`, you're throwing it away.  As stated in the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#read%28%29), *"**The character read, or** -1 if the end of the stream has been reached"*

Answer (score 2):

Read returns the value read from the `InputStream` as an `int` value.

You are reading beyond the end of the file.

You should be reading the value and storing that into a variable which you can use...

```
FileReader fin = null
try {
    fin = new FileReader("numbers.txt");
    int in = -1;
    while((in = fin.read()) > -1 ){
        System.out.print((char)in);
    }
} finally {
    try {
        fin.close(); 
    } catch (Exception exp) {}
}
```

I suggest you take a closer look at [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) for more details

ps- If you open a stream, you are expected to close it ;)

Answer (score 0):

FileReader.read() reads one or more bytes from file depending on the default encoding, converts it into a char, casts char to int and returns it. In case of EOF is reached it returns -1. This is how to read from a Reader till the EOS.

```
for(int c; (c = rdr.read()) != -1;) {
     System.out.print((char)c);
}
```